# What specs should I be looking for in a camera to record board-game sessions?

Tags: video, hardware, recommendation

I'm a computer science engineer with no experience and very little knowledge in camera and video processing.

I would like to record boardgame sessions (timelapse for example) and record boardgame rules description for my friends.

I'm therefore looking for a camera and I'm a bit lost. There are plenty of different camera on the market with lot of specs and I don't really know what I need to have to record boardgame sessions...

I think it has to have:

- HD capabilities
- A good microphone input both to catch my voice or multiple voices during a game
- No specific spec related to frame rate
- No waterproof capability

Could you help me with other different parameters I would need to care about when buying a camera?

Thanks for your help and precious advices

Random example :

P.s. I'm not looking for a shopping list here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take based on budget.  The first is to record audio in camera, the other is to record audio to a dedicated audio recorder and mix it with the video after.  The former is cheaper, but the latter will generally produce better quality.

As far as features, beyond HD, you are mostly just looking for good performance in whatever lighting conditions you will have and then looking for good color and video quality.  Best bet is to look at sample videos from them to find one you like.  I'd also recommend taking a look at the GoPro, it's one of the better, cheaper video cameras available and would probably work well for your needs.

If you want something more general purpose, you could also look at a DSLR with video capabilities such as a Canon T4i which would allow for high quality stills as well as high quality video.

Your best bet for narrowing down your choices is really going to be to think about what else you might want to do with it and how much you would like to spend, then look at what is in your price range.

If you do want a dedicated audio recorder, the Zoom H4n is a reasonably cheap and decent option that will allow external microphones to be used for recording audio.

Comment: Is there any reason why the video and the stop-motion must use the same camera?

Comment: The DLSR option is not possible because I already own a canon eos 450d and I don't want to change (at least for now)... I thought about GoPro but It seems to me it's a cheap camera for people who want to record themselves during sport session... Maybe my jugement is totally wrong........

Comment: I've already created a timelapse with my 450d and a laptop to trigger the shots... A bit heavy solution... But it works well... I want to record proper video though...

Comment: @AndyM - unless you are looking to spend considerably more money than the cost of a GoPro, it is one of the better quality video cameras for the price.  Many professional videographers use it when a small, cheap camera is necessary or when they need an array of cameras.  It won't beat a mid-range DSLR's video, but it's also a lot cheaper than a mid-range DSLR.  It is competitive or superior to a cheap DSLR in terms of sensor quality, but of course has the limitation of a fixed lens.

Comment: @AJ henderson Which model of the gopro do I need... Example : do I need 60 fps for this?

Comment: @AndyM - you shouldn't need anything fancy.  A basic model with an LCD back would probably work fine.  Your needs are very basic.  If it will be pretty dim, then it might be worth going for the higher end one for the better low light performance, but you are probably fine with the white edition and an LCD back.

Comment: @AJ Henderson - Actually, gopro dont have LCD in the back right? And tne white edition is only 5 MP... What about the light? Do I need an extra light with that kind of camera?

Comment: @AndyM - the GoPro has an LCD back that you buy as an accessory.  I was just reminding you that you would need one if you want to see what you are pointing the camera at.  HD video is only 2 megapixels and you have a DSLR for stills.  You shouldn't need an extra light as long as it isn't a dimly lit room.  I was just pointing out that the only relevant advantage the Black model has over the white for you would be the low light performance if you need to shoot in a dimly lit room.

Comment: @AJ Henderson - Considering the price of a gopro + voice recorder, should'nt go for a better quality camera that will last longer and be used in other part of my life (maybe kids or something), such as Canon Legria HF-G30 or Panasonic HC-X920? Will I need a external mic with those better camera as well? Thanks for your time and precious answers!

Comment: @AndyM - The GoPro captures audio as well.  The point of the audio recorder is that on camera audio is never very good.  It picks up the operational noises of shooting and is not able to take external inputs from good quality mics.  Using external audio produces better quality audio and is done on virtually all professional production work (unless the camera is really high end and allows professional microphones to be fed in to it.)  You could get a higher end camera that is more general purpose (that's why I initially suggested a DSRL) but an audio recorder would still improve the quality.